# How to use regexp to find numbers either before or after "/"

Tags: python, regex

I have different products, there are 4 different ways they can be presented.

1/ABC12345

ABB122456

ABD1236/1

1/AEC1256/2

The number on the left is the version of the release and the number on the right is the configuration version. Whenever this information is available I want to store it.

So for the first row I think I could do something like

```
 [rel_version,config_ver] = re.search(....,prod_no)
```

which should return

```
 rel_version = 1 and config_ver = None
```

And in the fourth row I want to return
     rel_version = 1, config_ver = 2

How would I write the correct search formula for this? Maybe re.split(...) could also work? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
product = "1/AEC1256/2"

match = re.match("([0-9]*)/?([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/?([0-9]*)", product)
rel_version, product_code, config_ver = match[1], match[2], match[3]
```

To explain:

- `([0-9]*)` will match zero or more numerals at the start as a captured group
- `/?` will match an optional `/`
- `([A-Z]+[0-9]+)` will match the `ABC12345` in the middle
- another `/?` and `([0-9]*)` for the numerals at the end

This will get the versions as strings - to parse, you can call `int`:

```
rel_version = int(rel_version) if rel_version != "" else None
```